# How to have Siri pick from the list s/he just read to me?

Tags: iphone, siri

Calling my friend XYZ using voice dial has become as easy as dictating one if his cell numbers to dial.

***Siri will recite:***
I have two numbers for XYZ. Which number would you like to call?
(abc) def-ghij   or   (pqr) stu-vwxy?

How do I pick?

I try insisting *the first one*, to which s/he replies "I don't know what you mean by 'the first one'".

How do I select a number without touching the screen and without reciting the entire phone number back?

*I am looking for an answer other than choosing unique types (eg, setting one of his cell numbers to "pager" instead.)*

iOS 7.1.2, iPhone 5s

Answer (score 1):

*"I am looking for an answer other than choosing unique types (eg, setting one of his cell numbers to "pager" instead.)"*

then I have no answer ;-)

Change the type & you can just say the type, cell [US] mobile [UK], office, home, etc.

You don't even have to wait for the list, you can just say to Siri, "Call Fred, cell."
 So long as there's only one Fred & one cell number listed for him.

If there are 2 Freds, then "Call Fred Smith"; 2 cells, then differentiate 'work cell' or 'cell 2' etc